# Well-ordering on the integers: "every subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ has a least element", but what about $\mathbb{Z}$ itself?

Tags: integers, well-orders

The integers are well-ordered.

If I take the entire set of integers though, there is no least element! Isn't the entire set of integers a valid subset of the integers?

Or (and I suspect this is the case), subset here is really in the very strictest of senses (i.e. $\mathbb{Z} \not\subset \mathbb{Z}$)?

Comment: The definition of wellordering includes the improper subset; $\mathbb Z$ is simply not wellordered.

Comment: Every subset of $\mathbb Z^+$ has a least element, Not $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I think it is important to state, the integers are not well ordered *on the "greater than" order*.  There are different orders on which they are. Example: sort the integers by absolute value and put all the positives before the negatives and put zero so that everything is sorted before it.

Comment: The even integers will be a proper subset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The integers are not well-ordered. Take, for example, the subset of all even integers - there is no least element.

I think you're thinking of the naturals, $\mathbb{N}$, in which case this is true.

Comment: Hrmm. I distinctly recall my professor mentioning that the integers are well ordered...maybe he means the positive integers (i.e. the naturals)! Okay, will confirm!

Comment: @user89 He sadly may have said that - doesn't mean it's right.

Comment: After all, teachers do make mistakes. I should know.

Comment: The integers *can* be well ordered if you use a different order.  But the greater than order won't work.  You can take proper subsets like the even numbers. Or any unbounded above or below infinite set to get a counter example.

Comment: If you order the integers by absolute value with the positives before it's negative counter part (or vice versa), then the integers are well ordered.  That's a different order.

Answer (score 2):

On $\mathbb{Z}$ (as on any set, if you accept the axiom of choice) there of course exists a well-order (let $0$ be the least element, with $0 < 1 < -1 < 2 < -2 < ...$). However, the typical order is not a well-order; it's merely a total order.

Answer (score 0):

With the standard "<" order the integers are not well ordered.  But if you use a different order the can be.

One such order I'll call "$\langle $which I'll define as. $a\langle b $ if $|a|<|b|$ and $-a \langle a $.  That's a well-ordering.

Another  is so that $0$ is the last number, every positive number is before any negative  number, and otherwise they are sorted by absolute value.

Or you could put them in alphabetical order in english.